# Route redirection after login in laravel nova

Tags: laravel

In laravel nova, I want to redirect after login to the resource page (like http://localhost/nova/resource/someresource), not to the default dashboard.

I have tried changing

redirectTo() in Laravel/nova/src/http/controller/loginController.php
to return my desired URL but this is showing a 404 error. then I changed "path" in config/nova.php to the desired URL but this also shows 404 error.
Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: is there any url available in your laravel project ?

Answer (score 0):

The default path is nova/resources/. But you were missing "s" in "resource"

change it back to http://localhost/nova/resource**s**/someresource